# How to predict something in R given two specifications?

Tags: r, lm, predict

I have a very large data set. Here is an example of some of it.

```
                          Car sport SUV Wagon Minivan Pickup AWD RWD  MSRP Invoice EngineSize Cylinders  HP City.MPG Hwy.MPG Weight
          Chevrolet Aveo 4dr     0   0     0       0      0   0   0 11690   10965        1.6         4 103       28      34   2370
 Chevrolet Aveo LS 4dr hatch     0   0     0       0      0   0   0 12585   11802        1.6         4 103       28      34   2348
      Chevrolet Cavalier 2dr     0   0     0       0      0   0   0 14610   13697        2.2         4 140       26      37   2617
      Chevrolet Cavalier 4dr     0   0     0       0      0   0   0 14810   13884        2.2         4 140       26      37   2676
   Chevrolet Cavalier LS 2dr     0   0     0       0      0   0   0 16385   15357        2.2         4 140       26      37   2617
           Dodge Neon SE 4dr     0   0     0       0      0   0   0 13670   12849        2.0         4 132       29      36   2581
```

What I want to do is predict the horsepower of a sports car with a 3.5-liter engine. I am honestly not too sure where to start. I have made these models for finding the horsepower of a sports car.

```
sportFilter <- cars$sport==1
hpModelSport <- lm(cars$HP[sportFilter] ~ cars$EngineSize[sportFilter])
```

And this for engine size.

```
hpModel <- lm(HP ~ EngineSize, data = cars)
```

But how do I use both of these. And the engine size model is just general, how do I specify 3.5-liter?

Comment: Sure here you go
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5n-r165dW8FWXc1M1ZDcWQ5M0E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: `m <- lm(HP ~ EngineSize, cars, subset = cars$sport == 1) ; predict(m, data.frame(EngineSize = 3.5))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to predict `HP` based on `EngineSize` and `sport` you can do following:

```
cars <- read.table("d:/Downloads/04cars.csv", header =T, sep =",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
fit <- lm(HP ~ EngineSize + sport , data=cars)
vals <-  data.frame(EngineSize = 3.5, sport = 1)
predict(fit, newdata=vals)
```